# removing www with htaccess file for subdomains

Tags: .htaccess

I have a variety of sites that are subdomain specific sites. 
http://sub.domain.com  http://apple.domain.com etc.

users occasionally complain that the site is not working and then i find out they went to 
http://www.sub.domain.com or http://www.apple.domain.com and are met with a server error page of sorts

what kind of htaccess magic do i need to turn http://www.sub.domain.com ->  http://sub.domain.com

thanks

*fwiw i did search through previous questions before asking and did not find my answer

Comment: Are you sure it's a "server error page of sorts" and not a "host not found error page of sorts"?

Comment: Some browsers will redirect to `www.\1` if the original website timesout. This is unfortunate if the timeout is accidental, but the browser caches that a redirect is needed. Then your server redirects the client from www to regular, and the browser starts bouncing back and forth :(

Comment: @roman its actually a 'server default page'

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If the VHost is really pointing to the same docroot for www.sub.domain.com and sub.domain.com, you can place a .htaccess-file with following content in the doc-root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^sub\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://sub.domain.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

That will redirect all domains which are pointing to this docroot to sub.domain.com

**EDIT:**

For multiple Subdomains in one single .htaccess-file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.([^\.]*)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://%1.domain.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

This is untested from top of the head.

Comment: i am not sure what www.sub.domain.com is pointing to right now.. when i go there i get a 'server default page'.. ideally it would redirect to sub.domain.com  ( so i guess im looking for more of a redirect thne just a url rewriting )

Comment: My answer is already a redirect (http statuscode 301 - permanently moved)

Comment: awesome. one last thing and i am not sure if your code already takes this into account or not.. but the subdomain should be a wildcard ( is that right? ) as i have multiple subdomains...