# Configuring apache2 vhost

Tags: apache, ssl, vhosts

I have the following vhost below, my goal with him is:

- Redirect all access to https (OK)
- Configure my ssl certificate (OK)
- Remove www from url

I still can not configure my vhost to remove the www and force the url (using 301) to the url without the www

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine on
    ReWriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /usr/local/ssl/api_site_com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /usr/local/ssl/myserver.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /usr/local/ssl/api.site.com.cer

    ServerName api.site.com
    ServerAlias www.api.site.com

    DocumentRoot "/var/www/api.site.com/public"

    <Directory "/var/www/api.site.com/public">
        Options Includes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Could anyone help me?

Comment: In a VHost that is specified for `*:80` you will most likely not encounter any port _other_ than 80 in any case … As for the actual problem, what have you done so far to debug this? Checked the access log, and enabled rewrite logging to see what actually happens? Have you first of all made sure this VHost is even handling the incoming HTTP request (since there’s no ServerName specified there)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [removing www with htaccess file for subdomains](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894531/removing-www-with-htaccess-file-for-subdomains)

Answer (score 0):

I use these two lines to remove the 'www':

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)         http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```